# skipping if statement if condition met and continue executing the code below php

Tags: php, if-statement

I will try to explain what I want to achieve with commented code.

what I am trying to do is skip through if statement if the condition is met and continue executing the code outside conditional statement.

```
<?php
  if (i>4) {
    //if this condition met skip other if statements and move on
  }

  if (i>7) {
    //skip this
?>

<?php
  move here and execute the code
?>
```

I know about the break, continue, end and return statement but that is not working in my case.

I hope this clears my question.

Comment: break and continue work only inside looping.

Comment: You could simply wrap what should be skipped in an else-statement? That's kinda what I think if-else are made for. As someone said earlier aswell: how about the if(i>4) followed by if(i>7). If they should be used the if(i>7) should be the first condition to check.

Answer (score 4):

If your first condition met and you want to skip other condition you can use any **flag** variable as below :

```
<?php
        $flag=0;
        if (i>4)
        {
          $flag=1;
        //if this condition met skip other if statements and move on
        }

        if (i>7 && flag==0)
        {
        //skip this
        ?>

        <?php
        move here and execute the code
        ?>
```

Comment: Why not just put the other if statements in the "else" from the first one?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`goto`](http://php.net/goto)

```
<?php
if (i>4)
{
//if this condition met skip other if statements and move on
goto bottom;
}

if (i>7)
{
//skip this
?>

<?php
bottom:
// move here and execute the code
// }
?>
```

But then again, lookout for dinosaurs.

[image: goto xkcd]

Answer (score 3):

Use `if-elseif-else`:

```
if( $i > 4 ) {
    // If this condition is met, this code will be executed,
    //   but any other else/elseif blocks will not.
} elseif( $i > 7 ) {
    // If the first condition is true, this one will be skipped.
    // If the first condition is false but this one is true,
    //   then this code will be executed.
} else {
    // This will be executed if none of the conditions are true.
}
```

Structurally, this should be what you're looking for.  Try to avoid anything that will lead to spaghetti code like `goto`, `break`, or `continue`.

On a side note, your conditions don't really make much sense.  If `$i` is not greater than 4, it will never be greater than 7, so the second block would never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I typically set some sort of marker, such as:

```
<?php
    if (i>4)
    {
    //if this condition met skip other if statements and move on
    $skip=1;
    }

    if (i>7 && !$skip)
    {
    //skip this
    ?>

    <?php
    move here and execute the code
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  while(true)
  {
    if (i>4)
    {
    //if this condition met skip other if statements and move on
    break;
    }

    if (i>7)
    {
    //this will be skipped
    }
  }    
?>

    <?php
    move here and execute the code
    ?>
```

Comment: if you want to avoid infinite looping during all false..use int i = 0; while(i<1){ //your if statements; i++;